# In how many ways can i order 26 letters given this conditions

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can i order 26 different letters in a way that:

**1.** I keep the letters A,B,C always together and in this order

**2.** A,B,C together but **not necessarily** in this order

**3.** A,B,C don't come out together

For **1.**  i think the solution is $$ 23! $$ but i am not sure, given the letters could be in different positions in the order, so maybe i need another calculation for getting this.

For **2.** i think the solution is $$ 23!*3! $$

And **3.** i think it would be the total number of orders of the 26 letters minuts de result of **2.** wich i think it would be $$ 26! - 23!*3! $$

Comment: For the first, tape A, B, C together in that order. We have $23$ regular letters and a superletter. There are $24!$ ways to arrange them.

Comment: the other results are right?

Comment: Does # 2 mean definitely **not** in ABC order?

Comment: You are welcome. For 2) *not necessarily* in this order would be $(3!)(24!)$. But *not* in this order would be $(3!-1)(24!)$.  The answer to 3) would in any case be along your lines, $26!-3!24!$.

Comment: User58220 #2 means ** not necessarily ** in that order, now i edit my mistake, i am sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot again André, i got the point now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For 1, imagine ABC as a single letter. Then there are 24 letters and the answer is 24!.
- For 2, there are 3! times as many combinations as before since ABC can be in any order so the answer is 6 * 24!.
- For 3, it is the total number of combinations minus those of answer 2, so 26! - 6 * 24!

So your intuition is correct but instead of 23! use 24!